# function that returns nothing in void call

Tags: r, function, data.table

I confused when I created the following simple function. 
If I do not assign the class in the temp then I see nothing on the screen when I execute the function (without print or assigning to anything)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
    my_percentage <- function(datatable, variable ){ 
            temp <- datatable[, .N, keyby = c(variable)]
            temp[, percentage := N/sum(N)]
             # temp <- as.data.table(temp)
            return(temp)
    }

my_percentage(iris %>% as.data.table(), variable = "Species")
# print(my_percentage(iris %>% as.data.table(), variable = "Species"))
```

However if I assign any class in the object that I will return it will be fine.

```
my_percentage <- function(datatable, variable ){ 
            temp <- datatable[, .N, keyby = c(variable)]
            temp[, percentage := N/sum(N)]
            temp <- as.data.table(temp)
            return(temp)
    }

my_percentage(iris %>% as.data.table(), variable = "Species")
```

Can anyone explain to me why ?

Comment: `my_percentage(data.table(iris), "Species")[]` works for me. Generally, you have to do `[]` after a `:=` inside a function, thanks to a quirk.